# ReferenceError: window is not defined with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, fly

Good evening, I'm using react 16.3.2 on Ubuntu and am wanting to integrate my new react application with [this software](https://github.com/superfly/fly).

My webpack.fly.config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const bundlePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
query: { presets: ['react']}
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    publicPath: bundlePath,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist"
  },
  plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ]
};
```

Which I don't think is the issue, because when I run `fly server` the server begins to run, but when I go to refresh my **localhost** webpage, I get the error below:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at module.exports (bundle.js:5:41)
>       at bundle.js:728:10
>       at ()
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@fly/fly/lib/default_context_store.js:47:30

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And my index.html:

```
<!-- sourced from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>React Starter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

React and Webpack are both still pretty new to me, so I'm not even sure what this error is or what it means.

Could someone shed some light here and point me in the right direction?

Comment: what's fly?????

Comment: looks like express, a nodejs server...

Comment: Fly is a JavaScript CDN startup - see here https://fly.io. I’m working on integrating their tech with React because they go hand in hand.

Comment: I would guess you or it (the software) are accidentally including file(s) that were not meant to be included server side

Comment: Thanks Patrick, can you elaborate on that? Where would I have told it this? In the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Search for 'window' in your code and make sure it is executed when client side using !**SERVER** or similar.